# jQuery UI slider not working in Wordpress theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having issues making jQuery UI's slider to work on my Wordpress theme.

I have enqueued the script still no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/library/js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js', false);

wp_register_script('jquery_ui', get_template_directory_uri().'/library/js/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery-ui-core'),'1.7.3');

wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri().'/library/css/jquery-ui.css');


wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_enqueue_script('jquery_ui');
```

Answer (score 7):

Why not use the WordPress inbuilt scripts? if you only want to use jquery ui slider then enqueue in the following way:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider');
```

Comment: Thanks for saving my hours.